# Not expected behavior of ModelMapper::map()

Tags: java, spring, rest, modelmapper

I use ModdelMapper::map() to update entities.

I have entity and dto:

```
@Entity
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Data
public class CustomerOrder {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<LineItem> lineItems;

    private Long customerId;

@Data
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class OrderRequest {

    @NotNull
    private Long customerId;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Products is mandatory")
    private List<LineItemDTO> lineItems;
```

My controller:

```
   @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<OrderResponse> updateOrder(@PathVariable Long id,
                                                     @Valid @RequestBody OrderRequest orderDto){

        final Optional<CustomerOrder> orderById = repository.findById(id);

        return orderById
                .map(order -> {
                    mapper.updateEntity(orderDto, order);
                    repository.save(order);
                    return ResponseEntity.ok(mapper.toDto(order));
                })
                .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
    }
```

I see that the Id field is updated with a value of customerId.
Why is this happening?